# Why wouldn't Rails generators create attributes and methods for a specific model?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, attributes, generator, sti

I've got two models in my application using STI: Entry and Sugar, they're very simple.

Entries:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: entries
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  created_at :datetime        not null
#  updated_at :datetime        not null
#  user_id    :integer
#  type       :string(255)
#

class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Sugar (note the lack of `amount` in the schema info from the annotate gem):

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: entries
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  created_at :datetime        not null
#  updated_at :datetime        not null
#  user_id    :integer
#  type       :string(255)
#

class Sugar < Entry
  attr_accessible :amount
end
```

I created the Sugar model by running `rails g model Sugar amount:integer` and then edited it to be a subclass of the Entry model.  The migration generated created an amount column:

```
class CreateSugars < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :sugars do |t|
      t.integer :amount

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And the column exists in my database:

```
bridges_development=# \d sugars
                                     Table "public.sugars"
   Column   |            Type             |                      Modifiers                      
------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------
 id         | integer                     | not null default nextval('sugars_id_seq'::regclass)
 amount     | integer                     | 
 created_at | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at | timestamp without time zone | not null
Indexes:
    "sugars_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

However, the "amount" attribute and/or methods don't seem to exist.  Here's an example:

```
1.9.2-p290 :002 > s.amount = 2
NoMethodError: undefined method `amount=' for #<Sugar:0xb84041c> (...)

1.9.2-p290 :003 > s = Sugar.new(:amount => 2)
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: amount (...)
```

Why wouldn't the `amount` attribute and associated methods be made available?

Comment: isn't STI supposed to be N models - 1 table? Sugar is accessing table entries, where there is no attribute amount.

Comment: tokland - I think you're right... I knew this question would be an oversight as soon as I posted it.

Comment: @nilmethod: ok, posted as answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of STI is N models - 1 table. `Sugar` is in fact accessing table `entries`, where there is no attribute `amount`.

Answer (score 1):

When you made sugar inherit from entry that made rails use STI (single table inheritance)

In this scheme all the classes are stored in the base class's table (entries) and the type column stores the name of the subclass. Because they all share the same table, they also share the same attributes: the sugars table won't be used at all

If you don't want this you can either make entry an abstract class

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

In which case there would be no entries table but there would be a sugars table (and one for each other subclass of Entry).

Another way is to put the code that Entry and Sugar should share into a module.